# activex control fails for non-local user account

Tags: activex

I have an ActiveX control built as a dll, installed via regsvr32, and launched on my website via:

```
<object id="customControl" type="application/x-custom-plugin">
```

Registering the dll requires a user account with admin access, which is fine.  The problem lies in using the webpage with certain user accounts.

1. Log in with local non-admin account, use local admin account to install
2. Log in with network domain non-admin account, use local admin account to install
3. Log in with network domain admin, install

In all cases:
- local non-admin account: **WORKS**
- local admin account: **WORKS**
- network domain non-admin account: **FAILS**

**Question:** With IE8 and IE9 on Windows 7, how can I install an ActiveX control in such a way that non-admin network domain user accounts can use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With this feature you can event install ActiveX without admin privileges:

[Non-Admin ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: It's OK that admin access is needed to install.  The issue is after the install, the control does not run on the webpage for network domain non-admin users.

Comment: Properly registered control should work for all users, independently of admin rights. It's hard to say what's wrong in your case, but why you don't want to do installation from CAB file? It much easier for end user to click install instead of running msi or regsvr with your library. This is a proper way recommended by design and should work for all cases.

Comment: Our client wants as few hoops as possible.  This means we have one chance with an installer with admin privileges and then everything should work.  This is why we're manually registering the active x control via regsvr32 rather than through the cab method.  Do you know if local vs network user accounts makes any difference for active x controls?  Or am I pursuing the wrong lead here?  Thanks!